# Using Google Cloud Tasks Using cURL or Without SDK/gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

Is it possible to interact with Google services such as [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) using nothing more than cURL?

There are several examples for different languages available on the '[create task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create)' section of their API docks, but I don't see anything that does not require the SDK (using cURL for example.)

Ultimately I'm looking to create Cloud Tasks externally without having to include any 3rd party code.

Comment: I have recently had the same question, and managed to answer it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644213/accessing-google-cloudtasks-api-without-using-googles-sdks?noredirect=1#comment119570532_67644213

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cloud Tasks API to manages the execution of large numbers of distributed requests [Cloud Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/).

For example to create a new queue called `mynewqueue` using [Method: projects.locations.queues.create](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues/create) you can use :

```
   curl --request POST \
   'https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/v2beta3/projects/my- 
    project/locations/europe-west2/queues?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"projects/my-project/locations/europe-west2/queues/mynewqueue"}' \
 --compressed
```

where YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN is the output of :

```
   gcloud auth print-access-token
```

and YOUR_API_KEY is optional.

To test if the command was successfull:

```
   gcloud tasks queues list
   #output mynewqueue   RUNNING  1000              500.0            100
```

Comment: Is the token generated with `gcloud auth print-access-token` permanent or would it need to be re-generated regularly?

Comment: The maximum token lifetime is 1 hour (3,600 seconds) [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the [Cloud Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/) without using the client libraries.

However, if you are looking for an easy local way to [create queues](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues) and tasks, I recommend using the [Cloud SDK (`gcloud` CLI tool)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing). This gives you the ability to easily manage your resources without having to roll your own script and authentication. 
To create an HTTP targetted task:

```
gcloud tasks create-http-task <TASK_ID_IF_NEEDED> --queue=QUEUE --url=URL
```

There are additional flags to easily add a header, a scheduled time, a request body, etc.