# Accessing Google CloudTasks API without using Google's SDKs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to use Google cloudtasks from Cloudflare workers.
This is a JS environment limited to web-workers standards minus some things that Cloudflare didn't implement.
Bottom line - I can't use Google's provided SDKs in that environment.
I'm trying to call the API using simple fetch, but always fail on the authentication part.

The [discovery document](https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2) says that

```
"parameters": {
   ...
   "key": {
      "description": "API key. Your API key identifies your project and provides you with API access, quota, and reports. Required unless you provide an OAuth 2.0 token.",
      "location": "query",
      "type": "string"
   }
}
```

So I tried calling the api with `?key=MY_API_KEY` query param
Didn't work.

I also tried generating a token using Service Account downloaded json file with [this library](https://github.com/sagi/workers-jwt)
Didn't work.

I tried following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth) to generate oauth access token which was what the error message told me that I need. But

1. running the command `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` returned the error:

   ```
   WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable onattempt 1 of 3. Reason: timed out
   WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable onattempt 2 of 3. Reason: timed out
   WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable onattempt 3 of 3. Reason: [Errno 64] Host is down
   WARNING: Authentication failed using Compute Engine authentication due to unavailable metadata server.
   ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
   ```

   The env variable above is set correctly to the service-account json file.
2. Even if it worked, I didn't understand how am I supposed to use it from my code, while it uses the cli tool `gcloud`

So my question is this - how can I access Google's cloud APIs from Cloudflare workers (web-workers javascript env.), specifically I'm interested in Cloudtasks, without using any CLI tool or Google SDK.
More specifically - how can I generate the required oauth2 access token?

Comment: For point 1, which Compute Engine Scopes are enabled?

Comment: AFAIK, Cloud Tasks does not accept API Keys for authorization. You must use an OAuth Access Token.

Comment: @JohnHanley It seems that you're right. The question is how can I generate OAuth access token without using Google's SDK?

Comment: Google search. There are many good articles on generating tokens. I have written several articles with source code on my website.

Comment: Of course I google searched first. Still, couldn't find it. Your hint for your own site gave me a starting point. After migrating your code from python to js, finding the right scope for cloudtasks (which was hidden in the api discovery json), I finally made it work. Thanks for the hints. I'll add an answer in case someone needs it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @john-hanley [blog post](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/) I was able to make the following code work:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); //in cloudflare workers env. this is not needed. 'fetch' is globally available
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const q = require('querystring');

async function main() {
    const project = 'xxxx';
    const location = 'us-central1';
    const scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    
    const queue = 'queueName';
    const parent = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}/queues/${queue}`
    const url = `https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/v2/${parent}/tasks`

    const sjwt = await createSignedJwt(json.private_key, json.private_key_id, json.client_email, scopes);
    const {token} = await exchangeJwtForAccessToken(sjwt)

    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }

    const body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({"c":"b"})).toString('base64'); //Note this is not a string!
    const task = { //in my case the task is HTTP request that google will send to my service outside GCP. You can create an appEngine task instead
        httpRequest: {
            "url": "https://where-google-should-send-the-task.com",
            "httpMethod": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                "Authorization": "only-if-you-need-it"
            },
            "body": body
        }
    };
    const request = {
        parent: parent,
        task: task
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers
    })

    const res =  await response.json()
    console.log(res)
}

async function createSignedJwt (pkey, pkey_id, email, scope) {
    const authUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    const options = {
        algorithm: "RS256",
        keyid: pkey_id,
        expiresIn: 3600,
        audience: authUrl,
        issuer: email
        // header: { //this is not needed because it's jsonwebtoken's default behavior to add the correct typ when the payload is a json
        //     "typ": "JWT"
        // }
    }
    const payload = {
        "scope": scope
    }
    return jwt.sign(payload, pkey, options)
}

/**
 * This function takes a Signed JWT and exchanges it for a Google OAuth Access Token
 */
async function exchangeJwtForAccessToken(signedJwt) {
    const authUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    const params = {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": signedJwt
    }
    const body = q.stringify(params);
    const res = await fetch(authUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body
    })
    if (!res.ok) {
        return {
            error: "Could not fetch access token. " + await res.text()
        }
    }
    const resJson = await res.json();
    return {
        token: resJson.access_token
    }
}

// for convenience, I'm placing the JSON here. For production it should be stored in secret-manager or injected via environment variable
const json = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "xxxx",
    "private_key_id": "xxxx",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "xxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxx%40xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}


main()
```